# How can I prove $|\tan(x) +\tan(y) | \ge |x+y|$ with the Mean Value Theorem?

Tags: trigonometry

> How can I prove
>   $$|\tan(x) +\tan(y) | \ge |x+y|$$ for all $x, y\in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$?

I'm trying to do it with the mean value theorem but I can't use it for this equation, right? Since there is a "+" between $\tan x$ and $\tan y$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question.

Comment: It is not always true.  Suppose, $x = \frac {\pi}{2}  + a, y = \frac {\pi}{2}  - a$  then $|\tan x + \tan y| = 0$ while $|x+y| = \pi.  x,y$ must be chosen such that  for all $c\in (x,y), \tan c$ is continuous.

Comment: Right! I will add that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact that
$|\tan(x)-\tan(y)| \geq |x-y| \times \inf({\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}}) = |x-y|$

Comment: Ya right but can I do that because there is a plus and not a minus?

Comment: Replace $y$ by $-y$ and note that $\tan(-y) = -\tan(y)$

Comment: So the equation is only true for tan(-y)? I'm not seeing that it would be the same

Comment: I showed the result for all $x$ and $y$. Now if it is true for some $y$, it must also be true for $-y$. I am just changing the symbol. So instead of $y$, I take $-y$ in what I gave. Now if you replace $y$ by $-y$ in the inequality I gave you get $|\tan(x)-\tan(-y)| \geq |x+y|$

Answer (score 1):

Apply the Mean Value Theorem to the function $f(x)=\tan(x)$. Since $f'(x)= 1+\tan^{2}(x)\ge1$ we get   $$|\tan(x)-\tan(y)|\ge{|x-y|}
$$ Note that $$\tan(-y)=-\tan(y).$$ Upon substitution of $-y$ for $y$ in $|\tan(x)-\tan(y)|\ge{|x-y|}$ we get $$|\tan(x)-\tan(-y)|\ge{|x+y|}
$$ Thus $$ |\tan(x)+\tan(y)|\ge{|x+y|}.$$